# Tracking uninstall record of android app using fabric

Tags: android, google-fabric

How can I track number of uninstalls of my app and get the list of users (if they were logged in while uninstalling the app) who have uninstalled it, using Fabric Crashlytics or Answers ? 
I want to do it so that I can send email to these users and get feedback from them.

Answer (score 5):

You will probably need clevertap or something that supports tracking uninstall event. I do not think this can be achieved via fabric